# Mnemonic not showing on a System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, mnemonics

I'm having some problems with Mnemonics and ContextMenus - although the Mnemonic property of the Menutem is set correctly the little underline wont show under the relevant key. Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    menu.MenuItems.Add("Hello &World");
    menu.Show(this, e.Location);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a windows setting to "Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the ALT key."  It is under Display Properties --> Appearance --> Effects on XP ...  Could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: Aahhhh - now you mention it its so obvious!

Comment: This was my solution! Except we are many years ahead in Windows 10... Here's how to find it: Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Change how your keyboard works -> Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Try using different text for your menu item. e.g "&Hello" or "&World". Also try setting the ShowShortcut to true, though .NET should do it for you by default.

```
menu.MenuItems[0].ShowShortcut = true;
```