# WInForms (Net 6) - Enable accelerator keys in the app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application in C#/Net 6. I have a menu strip with some menus and need to ensure that the accelerator keys are visible or each menu.

By default the app is picking up the Windows Host setting (which has them not visible) so I am wondering if there is a way to override this in application code?

Regards

Comment: Why would you not respect the system default?

Comment: [Is there a way to force mnemonic key to show out without pressing ALT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711698/3110834)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.  In answer to the previous comment, usability. For many end-users, if they can't see a feature it tends to not exist. Ease of use sometimes requires a visual prompt to get it noticed.  In this case I am focusing on keyboard users rather than mouse users.